# Slow down scroll speed only with selection

Tags: javascript, scroll

What I would like to achieve is really simple to explain, but a bit harder for me to implement.

The behaviour wanted is to slow down the scroll speed ONLY when the user has selected a text and scrolling page up / page down. The default behaviour is the following: https://gfycat.com/DismalDiligentEland

How could I obtain this effect in pure javascript (without jQuery)?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried writing some code to solve this on your own?